# Python asyncio, why doesn't asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED work as described?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Let's say I have two functions which return similar results. I want to call both and take the results of whichever returns first.
So lets say I have two async functions which wait 5 and 2 seconds like so:

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep


async def func_1():
    for i in range(5):
        print("func 1")
        sleep(1)
    return "slept for 5"


async def func_2():
    for i in range(2):
        print("func 2")
        sleep(1)
    return "slept for 2"
```

And I have a function which calls them like so:

```
async def competition():
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(func_1())
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(func_2())

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([task1, task2], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    print(len(pending))
    print(len(done))
```

As you see the competition function uses `asyncio.wait` to run the two tasks and returns the results based on the `FIRST_COMPLETED` function. The documentation defines `FIRST_COMPLETED` as:

> The function will return when any future finishes or is cancelled.

Also, I run the `competition` function as shown bellow.

```
asyncio.run(competition())
```

However, it does not return when one task is done. It returns when both are done.
Furthermore, the asyncio.wait() method is defined as a concurrent executer.

> Run awaitable objects in the aws iterable concurrently and block until the condition specified by return_when.

However, that is not what happens. The tasks run in a single thread and one runs after the other.
So the result that I get if I run the code is this:

```
func 1
func 1
func 1
func 1
func 1
func 2
func 2
0
2
```

Am I missing anything? Or have I misunderstood how it works?

FYI: I am using python 3.10.

Comment: `time.sleep` is a blocking call, you want `asyncio.sleep()` if you just want to sleep the coro, and not the entire program, otherwise you serialize your execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been using `time.sleep` in your code. When you chage your `time.sleep` calls in your code to `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, the results are:

```
func 1
func 2
func 1
func 2
func 1
1
1
```

I had some hard time wrapping my head around how async programming works, but in my understanding `asyncio` is by design supposed to run everything in a single thread (cooperative multithreading). It pauses the execution of a given function, when it encounters a call such as `await asyncio.sleep(1)` and moves on to execute other functions that are scheduled for execution. The ordinary `time.sleep` does not allow `asyncio` to pause the execution.